# is it possible to set specific file extensions as exclusive check out only, with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs, ssis

It seems that concurrent edits of certain file types (dtsx in my case) is just more hassle than it's worth.  How can I configure TFS (hopefully at the server, but at the client if necessary) such that certain file types are checked out as exclusive, while continuing to allow concurrent edits on "simpler" files, like .cs.

Answer (score 8):

Choose `Team` | `Team Foundation Server Settings` | `Source Control File Types...`. In this dialog you can add a new File Type for extension `dtsx` and specify that file merging and multiple check out are NOT to be allowed. Then any check out will be accompanied by a `lock`. You will see this already set up for some file types, eg Image Files.

Comment: Note you need to be a TFS admin to do this.